# Pass variables to python from a web server running LEMP

Tags: python, nginx, vps

what i am trying to do is from a vps i am running LEMP, to also serve a form which would have only one field and you can fill in there comma separated values.
Then i would take these values and pass them as arguments to a python script i wrote and finally the reply from the python script to be printed again in the same page as the form.

An example so this can be understood easier would be:
I visit this web server at domain.com and there i have an input field where i fill 10 email addresses each one separated by comma. Then i hit a submit button which takes these 10 values and runs a python script with them and for each one it responds back to this page with the result.

i am not sure on how to proceed with this as i need it to be secure as to not compromise the rest of the data in the server.

I saw flask which i have not used and if you are to suggest this please also mention how lightweight is flask in a situation of multiple queries to this form page per minute?